# C# or VB .net HtmlAgility: how to get nested span from portion of html page

Tags: c#, html, vb.net

Example file (a portion of HTML page):

```
<span class="test">English 
    <span> failed</span> 
     <span class="retake">no</span> 
</span>
```

HtmlAgilityPack Code Example:

```
node.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='test']").InnerText()
```

gives me:

```
English failed no
```

But I only need code which returns me line no. 2.:

```
<span> failed</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Descendants` to get the child nodes:

```
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='test']");
if (node != null && node.Descendants("span").Any())
{
    string result = node.Descendants("span").First().InnerText;
}
```